# Django and Ajax: CSRF token missing despite being passed

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to hit an API endpoint that I made using `django-rest-framework` when a button is pressed. I'm using jQuery's ajax method, and passing the csrf token, but am receiving an error that states `{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}`.

Here's my ajax request:

```
    $('#deactivateBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/v1/companies/{{ object.pk }}/',
            type: 'PATCH',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                'is_active': false,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                   $('#deactivateBtn').hide();
                   console.log('hiding');
                   $('#deactivateSuccess').show();
            }
        })
    });
```

and my authentication settings for `django-rest-framework`:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
        # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ]
    }
```

Why am I getting a CSRF error, despite passing the token in my ajax request? I've tried decorating my view with `ensure_csrf_cookie` from django.views.decorators.csrf, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: please show your corresponding view...

Answer (score 0):

Django will only parse the request body if the request method is `POST` and the content type is either `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In your example, neither is true, so Django won't parse the body and can't find the csrf token.

If you don't want to use a `POST` request with the appropriate content type, you need to pass the csrf token into the `X-CsrfToken` header. That method will work for any request. Django [recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) to use the following code:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

This will ensure that the token is only send when necessary, and won't be leaked to malicious sites accidentally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to use a POST method, though, that doesn't make sense -- I'm not creating a new item, I'm editing an existing one. How would I go about using a PATCH method?

Comment: @orange1 I'm sorry that wasn't clear. If you don't use a POST request with the appropriate content type, you need to use the `X-CsrfToken` header instead. That will work regardless of the request method.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the @knbk's answer, you need to set the `csrftoken` variable with

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

and in your `django-rest-framework` settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', // add this
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

[**Example App # 1**](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-do-i-implement-session-authentication-in-django-rest-framework/)

[Example App # 2](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-to-implement-token-authentication-with-django-rest-framework/)

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax)

[DjangoRestFramework docs - CSRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#csrf)

[DjangoRestFramework docs - Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a combination of the posted answers -- it looks like I needed the csrf-token header, but actually I can just fetch the csrf-token using the template tag:

```
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
            }
        }
    });
```

then there was also an issue with the content types that I was declaring being incorrect, so that changed to:

```
    // On click of deactivate button, Posting is marked as not active
    $('#deactivateBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/v1/companies/{{ object.pk }}/',
            type: 'PATCH',

            data: {
                is_active: false
            },

            success: function(data){
                   $('#deactivateBtn').hide();
                   console.log('hiding');
                   $('#deactivateSuccess').show();
            }
        })
    });
```

finally, changed django settings to include an authentication class:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        ),
        # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
        # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ]
    }
```